# Nest can't resolve dependencies of the AuthService (?, JwtService)

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, dependency-injection, jestjs, nestjs

I am having some problems with the test generated by default by nest js. I make sure my services are not circularly declared and are both fully exported service and imported module. I have tried other similar stack questions but it doesn't seem to be my case. Please tell me how to fix it. Thanks

here is my repository: https://github.com/ThanhDeveloper/NestJsApp

My auth controller:

```
export class AuthController {
  constructor(private readonly authService: AuthService) {}

  @Post('login')
  @UseGuards(AuthGuard('local'))
  @ApiBody({ type: LoginUserDto })
  @UseInterceptors(TransformInterceptor)
  @HttpCode(200)
  async login(@Request() req) {
    return await this.authService.login(req.user);
  }

  @Post('register')
  @UseInterceptors(TransformInterceptor)
  async signUp(@Body() registerUserDto: RegisterUserDto) {
    return await this.authService.register(registerUserDto);
  }
}
```

My auth service:

```
export class AuthService {
  constructor(
    private readonly userService: UsersService,
    private readonly jwtService: JwtService,
  ) {}
}
```

auth.module.ts:

```
@Module({
  imports: [
    PassportModule,
    UsersModule,
    JwtModule.register({
      secret: JWTKEY,
      signOptions: { expiresIn: TOKEN_EXPIRATION },
    }),
  ],
  providers: [AuthService, LocalStrategy, JwtStrategy],
  controllers: [AuthController],
})
export class AuthModule {}
```

user.module.ts:

```
@Module({
  controllers: [UsersController],
  providers: [UserProfile, UsersService, ...usersProviders],
  exports: [UsersService],
})
export class UsersModule {}
```

app.module.ts

```
@Module({
  imports: [
    ConfigModule.forRoot({ isGlobal: true }),
    DatabaseModule,
    UsersModule,
    AuthModule,
    CrawlersModule,
    AutomapperModule.forRoot({
      options: [{ name: 'classMapper', pluginInitializer: classes }],
      singular: true,
    }),
  ],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

err log: [image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- change `auth.controller.spec.ts` to

[image]

- change `auth.service.spec.ts` to

[image]

- change `users.controller.spec.ts` to

[image]

- change `users.service.spec.ts` to

[image]

All your errors will be gone

[image]

Comment: not working for me hmm. tks for your solutions

Comment: share the new error please. I made it work using your repo. snapshot attached

Comment: ``` 
  ● Test suite failed to run

    Jest worker encountered 4 child process exceptions, exceeding retry limit

      at ChildProcessWorker.initialize (../node_modules/jest-worker/build/workers/ChildProcessWorker.js:185:21)

Test Suites: 2 failed, 4 passed, 6 total
Tests:       4 passed, 4 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        9.996 s
```

Comment: I have updated some code for the project. You can check easily

Answer (score 0):

`UsersService` has a `UserRepository` injection. So if you want to test your controller or service that imports(or uses) `UsersService`, you must inject it or use repository mocking.

Comment: I'm wondering how will this be implemented?